# Change the source of Excel - Powerpoint linked charts:

Tags: excel, powerpoint

I created an excel template with 50+ sheets and a powerpoint file with 50+ slides, containing linked excel charts from mentioned template.

Every month, I need to build a new report by pasting the monthly data in the excel template's first sheet, which automatically populates all 50+ sheets and charts. However, when I save the file under a new name (say, February sales) the powerpoint remains linked to the empty excel template.

Is there a way how I can make Powerpoint recognise that I have saved the excel template under a new name (in a new map as well) and change the link to the February sales excel file?

Thanks a lot,

Pierre

Comment: That will require VBA. You can define the month variable to current and get value base on that

Comment: Use VBA or save the OLD template under a new name and paste your new data into the original file.